# Different runtime of async function

Tags: c#, function, asynchronous

The asynchronous function **foo** is called 4 times and each time we wait for the result with **.Result**.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sm = new Stopwatch();

        sm.Start();
        var result1 = foo().Result;
        sm.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("duration 1 : " + sm.Elapsed.ToString());

        sm.Reset();
        sm.Start();
        var result2 = foo().Result;
        sm.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("duration 2 : " + sm.Elapsed.ToString());

        sm.Reset();
        sm.Start();
        var result3 = foo().Result;
        sm.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("duration 3 : " + sm.Elapsed.ToString());

        sm.Reset();
        sm.Start();
        var result4 = foo().Result;
        sm.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("duration 4 : " + sm.Elapsed.ToString());
    }

    public static async Task<int> foo()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                x++;
            }
        });
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The first call takes more time than the others, e.g:

- duration 1 : 00:00:00.0016609
- duration 2 : 00:00:00.0001197
- duration 3 : 00:00:00.0001045
- duration 4 : 00:00:00.0000632

Calling another asynchronous function after the last call (e.g. function bar with the same body as foo) would take more time than fourth call of foo.
What is the reason?

Comment: Well, for one thing the [JIT compiler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation) has to do it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the first time you call the `foo` it is compiled to native code by the Just-in-time compiler, other calls execute the pre-compiled code which is why they work faster.